# Adsense- What is Pageviews?

Tags: adsense, pageviews

If I have 50 pages in my site and 5000 users came and visited all the pages..Is that considered 250,000 pageviews?

What is a pageview to be exact?..And do I need to put an ad on every page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check your analytics report which will show exact page views in a day. If all visitors read all pages then definitely it will be 50x5000; but I would recommend to add Ad units on those pages which has less bounce rate and higher visit time. Also, keep in mind content length. If content length is more than 600 words then you can use all three ad units otherwise use less number of units.

**Reference:** [Best placements for Google AdSense Link Ad units](http://www.duggu.org/google-adsense/best-placements-for-google-adsense-link-ad-units.aspx)